# How to optimize a conditional text translation?

Tags: conditionals

I am working on a short story written in french, and containing a number of short dialogs in english. A friend suggested it might be a courtesy to potential readers to tranlslate the english content into french by footnotes. I would like however to easily offer both versions, by changing a global parameter as shown in the MWE: with *and* without footnotes.  I wonder if the approach taken is optimal. Moreover, I am trying to come up with yet a third version that would be entirely in french, i.e. by replacing the english text by the content of the footnote, but also with a change of font from `\emph` to normal. I use the `\emph` font to distinguish the text in english from the core document in french.

Is there a practical way to do this, or is this overkill?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}

\def\lang {e} %variable used for conditional translated footnotes

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \emph{--- The manager needs to see you before you leave}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{}} {}{\footnote{\selectlanguage{french}   Monsieur, le patron veut vous voir avant votre départ !}}!

\selectlanguage{french}
Je tournai la tête et levai les yeux vers le visage de la serveuse. 

\item \emph{--- The manager needs to see you before you leave}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{e}} {}{\footnote{\selectlanguage{french}Monsieur, le patron veut vous voir avant votre départ !}}!
\selectlanguage{french}
Je tournai la tête et levai les yeux vers le visage de la serveuse. 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally come up with the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}

\def\lang {ef} %variable used for conditional text e=english, f=french, ef=english with translated footnotes

\newcommand{\CondText}[2]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{e}} {{\selectlanguage{english}\emph{#1}}} {}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{ef}} {{\selectlanguage{english}\emph{#1}}
\footnote{\selectlanguage{french} #2}} {}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{f}} {{\selectlanguage{french} #2}}{}
}%

\begin{document}
\CondText {--- Sir, the manager needs to see you before you go !} {--- Monsieur, le patron veut vous voir avant votre départ !}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your last question quickly: It is not overkill, but it is not comfortable and thereby a little impractical. In the following example (that contains also your attempt) I defined a macro - optimizing your approach, as requested - called `\englphrase` that works like `\englphrase[french translation]{english text}`. It will add a footnote with the french translation only if you give one in the optional argument.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}

\def\lang{e} %variable used for conditional translated footnotes

\let\markforphrase\emph
\newcommand{\englphrase}[2][]{%
\selectlanguage{english}
\markforphrase{#2}%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\footnote{\selectlanguage{french} #1}\fi
\selectlanguage{french}
}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \emph{--- The manager needs to see you before your leave!}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{}} {}{\footnote{\selectlanguage{french}   Monsieur, le patron veut vous voir avant votre départ !}}

\selectlanguage{french}
Je tournai la tête et levai les yeux vers le visage de la serveuse.

\item \emph{--- The manager needs to see you before your leave!}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{e}} {}{\footnote{\selectlanguage{french}Monsieur, le patron veut vous voir avant votre départ !}}
\selectlanguage{french}
Je tournai la tête et levai les yeux vers le visage de la serveuse.
\end{enumerate}

%A demonstration of the optimized approach
\medskip\hrule\medskip
\parindent=0in

---\englphrase[Monsieur, le patron veut vous voir avant votre départ!]{The manager needs to see you before your leave!}

Je tournai la tête et levai les yeux vers le visage de la serveuse.

---\englphrase{The manager needs to see you before your leave!}

Je tournai la tête et levai les yeux vers le visage de la serveuse.
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I missed and important point. You also need something like `\transltnoff` to switch off translations globally in order to provide both an english and a french version of your book easily. Try:

```
\newif\iftransltn
\transltntrue
\let\transltnoff=\transltnfalse %this is just to make the macro sound intuitive
\let\markforphrase=\emph
\newcommand{\englphrase}[2][]{%
\foreignlanguage{english}{\markforphrase{#2}}% thanks egreg :-)
\iftransltn%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \footnote{#1}
  \fi%
\fi%
}

%\transltnoff
```

Comment: I'd use `\foreignlanguage{french}{<French line>}` rather than `\selectlanguage{french}<French line>`; you're resetting languages too often.

Comment: I could not make your suggestion work. However this has led me to a simple solution: \def\lang {f} %variable use for conditional text e=english, f=french, ef=english with footnotes \newcommand{\CondText}[2]{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{ef}} {\emph{#1}\footnote{\selectlanguage{french} #2}} {}
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{f}} {\selectlanguage{french} #2}{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\lang}{e}} {\emph{#1}} {}
 }%
 
   
 \CondText{--- The manager needs to see you before you leave !}{Monsieur, le patron veut vous voir avant votre départ !}

Comment: @Yves, Did you really compile the complete example above? What are the exact error messages? (Maybe add them as an edit to your question.) However, your comment shows also a good approach because you now wrapped your idea into a macro, which also optimizes what you have done til yet. What do you think about adding this as an answer?

Comment: @Ruben. Your solution compiles fine and does the job. What I meant is that I could not make use of the `\transltnoff` addition. This may well be because I am a beginner and misused the additional code. Also statements like `\if\relax\detokenize` are really not understandable by me. However It was your idea to make a macro (that also brings a better sepearation between form and contents) that really helped me. I still have a minor concern. I am told by a friend familiar with typography, that a call for a note should in fact occur before the punctuation signs at the end of the sentences, and

Comment: @Ruben. (cont) not after, as in the examples above. However it seems that trying do do this would destroy some of the previous logic, and I am going to let it this way.